# Scrapy / How to select data directly nested into span

Tags: python, scrapy

One website I am trying to scrap has a specific structure for prices. It is something like :

```
<span class="sale-price" data-sup-product-price="" data-item-price="2.02" ...>
2,
<sup>02 E</sup>
</span>
```

It is possible to access directly the **data-item-price data** nested into the span ?

I mean, not something like :

```
response.css("span.sale-price").extract()
```

But another way with data-item-price ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `response.css("span.sale-price::attr(data-item-price)").get()` for getting data from this field. Or if you want to get all `span` with such field use selector `span[data-item-price]`.

Comment: Thank you again ! :) I didn't know I could select with ::attr(data-item-price)